# Wiki Tag Suggested Edits

Tags: feature-request

I was looking through some suggested edits and saw some for wiki tags, and one needed a small but pertinent change. The instructions initially indicate that this is possible, but then offer no edit choice, either in the list of actions:

> Approve, reject, or improve edits suggested by users.
>
> - Approve edits that clearly improve the post
> - Reject edits that fail to improve the post or that make it worse
> - Skip if you are not sure and want to go to the next suggested edit

or as one of the edit buttons:
[image]

I see that a Trusted User has the privilege of "Editing tag wikis without needing approval," and I am not at that level yet, but the way it is currently worded, it seems that I should be able to improve a suggested wiki edit and then vote to approve it with my additional input.
As it stands, I have only the choice to **Approve** the edit (which has one or more issues), or **Reject** the edit (which is a clear improvement over what was there previously).

I'd suggest that we either

1. Change the wording from the blockquote above to read

   > Approve or reject edits suggested by users.

or

2. Add another button similar to one that is seen when approving question/answer edits, allowing the reviewer to "Improve this edit."

Personally, I'd vote for choice number 2.

Comment: This is not a Puzzling-specific issue or something that can be changed per-site. On this meta, it will just be ignored. It really belongs on [meta.se], but over there it would probably be closed as duplicate of something several years old :-/

Comment: Thanks, @Randal'Thor, I appreciate the help.

Comment: In case anyone was curious as I was here is the link to said old request on meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95520/allow-improve-for-tag-wiki-edit-suggestions

Comment: @gabbo1092 My new Meta.SE question is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318778/suggested-edit-review-instructions-mistakenly-indicate-that-5k-users-can-improv?noredirect=1&lq=1). I've indicated in my question that the post you linked to is asking why they can't improve (insufficient Rep). My question is why is the choice being incorrectly offered to users with insufficient rep. Different question.